# update UI Main-thread from sub-thread AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface

i am a newbie to android and have lots of trouble to get a simple update for a gui working.

from my main class i call a AsyncTask:

```
RepeatTimerTask task = new RepeatTimerTask(text, timerDummy);
task.execute(null);
```

The async class is like follows

```
class RepeatTimerTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
private long startTime;
private TextView txtToUpdate;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
long mStartTime = 0;
RepeatTimer timer;
long timerLength = 0;

public RepeatTimerTask(TextView txtToUpdate, RepeatTimer timer) {
    this.txtToUpdate = txtToUpdate;
    this.timer = timer;
    startTime = new Date().getTime();
    this.timerLength = timer.getTime() * 1000;
}




protected void onProgressUpdate(String newText) {
    try
    {

      txtToUpdate.setText(newText);
      txtToUpdate.invalidate();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        HErrorHandler.log(e);
    }
}

protected void onPostExecute() {
    txtToUpdate.setText("ALAAAAAMMMM");
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { 

    while (true) {
        try {
            synchronized (this) {
                this.wait(100);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            HErrorHandler.log(e);
            break;
        }

        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        if (millis <= 0
                || System.currentTimeMillis() > timerLength + startTime) {
            break;
        }
        int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds = seconds % 60;

        // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!   HERE THE ERROR1 OCCOURS!!!!!!!
        //txtToUpdate.setText(String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds));
        //txtToUpdate.invalidate();
        String labelText = String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
        publishProgress(labelText);
    }
    return null;
}


}
```

I get an error when i try to update the TextView:

```
    02-08 06:19:01.857: W/System.err(5625): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
    02-08 06:19:01.887: W/System.err(5625):     at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2932)
    02-08 06:19:01.897: W/System.err(5625):     at android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:629)
    02-08 06:19:01.917: W/System.err(5625):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
    02-08 06:19:01.927: W/System.err(5625):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
    02-08 06:19:01.947: W/System.err(5625):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
    02-08 06:19:01.957: W/System.err(5625):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
    02-08 06:19:01.977: W/System.err(5625):     at android.widget.AbsListView.requestLayout(AbsListView.java:1102)
    02-08 06:19:01.997: W/System.err(5625):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
    02-08 06:19:02.007: W/System.err(5625):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
    02-08 06:19:02.030: W/System.err(5625):     at android.widget.TableLayout.requestLayout(TableLayout.java:226)
    02-08 06:19:02.037: W/System.err(5625):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
    02-08 06:19:02.057: W/System.err(5625):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8267)
    02-08 06:19:02.068: W/System.err(5625):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:5521)
    02-08 06:19:02.087: W/System.err(5625):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2724)
    02-08 06:19:02.097: W/System.err(5625):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2592)
    02-08 06:19:02.107: W/System.err(5625):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2567)
    02-08 06:19:02.127: W/System.err(5625):     at com.hdit.RepeatTimerTask.doInBackground(RepeatTimerTask.java:74)
    02-08 06:19:02.147: W/System.err(5625):     at com.hdit.RepeatTimerTask.doInBackground(RepeatTimerTask.java:1)
    02-08 06:19:02.159: W/System.err(5625):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
    02-08 06:19:02.177: W/System.err(5625):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
    02-08 06:19:02.187: W/System.err(5625):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    02-08 06:19:02.207: W/System.err(5625):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
    02-08 06:19:02.217: W/System.err(5625):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
    02-08 06:19:02.237: W/System.err(5625):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

What can i do to avoid this?

unfortunately the

> onProgressUpdate

is never reached.

thank you

Comment: I'm a little bit confused as to what you are trying to do - are you trying to update a progress dialog as your background thread is running - or update a text view AFTER the job is finished?

Comment: i try to update a label DURING (and also from) my backgroundthread is running.

Comment: Are you creating your Task in a non-main thread?

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, you created the RepeaterTask in a background thread. If that is the case, the AsyncTask will **not** be able to touch a view. AsyncTasks **must** be created in main thread to touch views.

Comment: The task is created within a onClick-Event in my main-activity

Comment: Where are you updating your label if you're getting that exception and `onProgressUpdate` is never reached...? Also, post your actual stack trace, not just the exception.

Comment: the out-commented text is where the exception occours. The call of publishProgress(labelText); does not trigger onProgressUpdate independently

Answer (score 1):

Your issue comes from your commented out code. You **cannot** update a view outside of the main thread. You are invalidating the textview in the Task (which runs in its own view). To stop the issue, you will need to refresh the textview in onProgressUpdate - not in soInBackground.

Comment: the problem is that onProgressUpdate is never reached!

Comment: Because you are trying to update a view in doInBackground. You **CANNOT** update a view, or setText(), or anything that has to do with the UI in any thread that is not the main thread. You must set the text either before you start the task, in onProgressUpdate, or after.

Comment: sorry, it has nothing to do with that... for sure i commented it out because the error occoured. I solved the problem now: i forgot the word "overwrite" on the onProgressUpdate and some litle things of the signature.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to overrride the onProgressUpdate correctly:

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values)
```

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 parts in an AsyncTask. You can update a view from any part except form `doInBackground`. Remove `publishProgress(labelText);` from there and you will reach `onProgressUpdate`.

Have a look here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html